# LoopbackJS (express) middleware (auth0) fails on production, but works on the local environment

Tags: node.js, express, loopbackjs, middleware

I have a middleware responsible for authorization: [loopback-auth-jwt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/loopback-auth0-jwt), and I want to apply it to most of the endpoints, but not to all of them. Some of the endpoints should be exposed, but if a request has the access token it should be used for authentication. So I wrote a middleware, that should check the token and if it's present authorize the user, otherwise it should do nothing, so user would be treated as anonymous. It works perfectly on the local environment, though it fails on the remote server. To be honest I don't even know how to debug that. Here is my middleware (it's not 1 to 1 code, but the general concept is here):

```
// Define routes that should be public and not protected by auth0 by default.
const EXCLUDED_ROUTES = [
  '/api/projects/',
  '/api/tasks/[a-z0-9]*',
  '/api/projects/(task)/[a-z0-9]*'
];

module.exports = server => {
  const auth0Jwt = require('loopback-auth0-jwt');
  const jwtDecode = require('jwt-decode');

  const authConfig = {
    // ...
  };

  const auth = auth0Jwt(server, authConfig);

  // Check if given URL should be considered as public or private route.
  // This function is working as desired.
  const isPublicRoute = url => {
    let isPublic = false;
    EXCLUDED_ROUTES.map(route => route.replace('/', '/')).forEach(pattern => {
      const regex = new RegExp(pattern);
      if (regex.test(url)) {
        isPublic = true;
      }
    });
    return isPublic;
  };

  // Middleware that depend on the result of isPublicRoute function applies auth0 middleware or not.
  const authMiddleware = async (req, res, next) => {
    const path = req._parsedUrl.pathname;

    if (isPublicRoute(path)) {
      // validate reuqest headers
      if (!(req.headers && req.headers.authorization)) return next();

      // ... some additional checks

      const userWithToken = await server.models.User.findOne({where: { email: userEmail }, include: ['accessTokens']});

      // no token was found, so we need to login user.
      if (!userWithToken.accessToken) {
        accessToken = await server.models.User.login({
          // data
        });
      }
      if (accessToken) {
        req.accessToken = accessToken;
        next();
      } else {
        next();
      }
    } else {
      // route is not public - apply auth0 middelware.
      server.use(path, auth.authenticated);
      next();
    }
  };

  // apply authMiddleware
  server.use(authMiddleware);

  server.enableAuth();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

So we've identified the issue. According to the loopback docs, `server.use(path, auth.authenticated)` will add the middleware, but since it's an express middleware it has no control on the order of the middleware execution, that's why random results were returned. 
So we've moved that to middleware.json and applied this middleware in the `auth` stage and it works like a charm.